# Package golang directory tree into a single file

Tags: go

Using Golang, if we have a folder tree like this:

```
foo/
  bar/
   baz/
     baz.go
   jazz/
     jazz.go
```

is there a way to package this folder into a single file for consumption by other go programs, but keep the namespacing, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool by Google Go team that does that: [bundle](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/cmd/bundle).

Comment: for extra credit, can you show an example of doing that with the fs tree in the OP? You also get extra credit points for upvoting the OP lulz.

Comment: This is still the best answer to the question.

Comment: @Kaveh Shahbazian any idea how to install the bundle tool? Can't find the installation instructions from the docs. I wish it were `go bundle` instead of `bundle`...

Comment: From the instructions on its page (https://github.com/golang/tools): `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/...`.